# More than one variable type in array

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I am busy with a dynamic 2d array and I have declared it as follows:

```
string** MakeArray(int row,int col)
{
    string** array;
    array = new string* [col];

    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        array[r] = new string [col];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Now I can place string values in the array. How can I place Integer values in the first column and strings in second and integers in third, if my array is 4 by 99?

Comment: An array by definition is a collection of **similar** data types. Why do you want to mix int and strings in it ?

Comment: I want to use the data in col-1 and lets say col-2 is a description of data and add col-1 with col-3(which is also in value) and display in col 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. Instead create a struct that will represent single record in a table, and contain a string and two integers. Then create one dimensional array of those structures.

```
struct record
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    int c;
};

record* MakeArray(int row)
{
    return new record[row];
}
```

better yet, ditch arrays and use std::vector:

```
std::vector<record> array(99);
```

Comment: The record* MakeArray(int row) can be classified as an object if i am not wrong.

Comment: @Monster what do you mean object? Its a function.

Comment: No that it is an object of the structure

Comment: @Monster, no MakeArray is a function that returns a pointer to array of record objects.

Comment: Ok. So how do i use the data in the struct?

Comment: @Monster after you create the array like so `record* array = MakeArray(99)` you can access for example the string in struct at index 10 like so `array[10].b`

Comment: can i also do the following  array[10] -> b

Comment: If you have a 2d array how will that work.Or is it three arrays. and how do you display it in a grid form.

Comment: @Monster try making a separate question for that.

Comment: @ yuri kilochek i will do that. One more question. How did you get so much rep?

Comment: @Monster you answer people's questions.

Answer (score 3):

The elements in an array are all the same type. To get what you're after, you probably want to start off rather differently, with an array of structs:

```
struct whatever { 
    int a;
    std::string b;
    int c;
};

std::vector<whatever> your_array;
```

Edit: although it's almost certainly a lousy idea, if you *really* need this to be a 2D array, you could try making all your elements the same type of union:

```
union whatever { 
    int a;
    std::string b;
};
```

This has some pretty severe limitations though -- in fact, putting a `std::string` in a union isn't officially supported at all. There's a fairly decent chance it'll work, but no guarantee of it at all. If you really, really need to do something like this, you can make that member of the union a pointer instead. That is guaranteed to work, but also guaranteed to be so clumsy that making mistakes with it is nearly inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at having a vector/array of tuples, if you have C++11 available to you? So you could do something such as:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

typedef std::tuple<int, std::string, int> MyTuple;

std::vector<MyTuple> MakeVector()
{
    std::vector<MyTuple> vecTuples;

     for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
     {
         vecTuples.emplace_back( std::make_tuple<int, std::string, int>( i, "Test"+i, i+5 ) );
     }

     return vecTuples;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a "strong-typed" language. One of the things that means is you cannot mix data types (unless they are related, like base-derived class hierarchical relationship).

In other words what you are doing is not what C++ directly supports.

Having said that there's something you can do that would do what you want - have an array of *triplets*, like this:

```
struct triplet
{
  int first;
  string second;
  int third;
};

triplet** MakeArray(...
```

What you are doing in your example looks alot like a JS code though. Maybe what you want is to store *all your data* as strings? Then yes, you can use a 2D array of strings, but that **requires** you to convert datum into string when storing it and converting back from string for calculations. Which is a major performance issue

Comment: from makeArray(...) What specified info must i enter there the row and the col, or my variables i used in the struct and can a access and place data.